# Doctrine Native Sql Query Failing with associative field

Tags: sql, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

Can't seem to figure out what is wrong here as my Entity seems to have the right annotations etc. Converting the SQL to run directly in Navicat it works.

Specific error is

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 120 near 'city_id = 2)': Error: Class Simpleweb\Entity\Product has no field or association named city_id
```

Product entity section related to the city_id (City is a OneToMany related Entity)

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="City", inversedBy="products")
 * @JoinColumn(name="city_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $city;
```

Code in controller is trying to build a dynamic query based on a number of filters the user selects. The one related to this tries to add city id numbers to the where clause:

```
public function findByPhrases($phrase, $sortBy = null, $cityFilter = null){
    $searchWords = $this->phraseToWords($phrase);
    $result = null;

    if(!is_null($searchWords)){
        /*
         * Build query, e.g. below:
         *
         * SELECT * FROM products
         * WHERE description_short
         * (LIKE '%sander%' OR name LIKE '%sander%') AND
         * (city_id = 1 OR city_id = 3)
         */
        try{
            $sql = "SELECT p FROM Simpleweb\Entity\Product p WHERE ";

            // Append an OR where clause onto the end for each word
            $sql .= "(";
            foreach($searchWords as $word){
                $sql .= "(p.description_short LIKE '%$word%') OR (p.name LIKE '%$word%') OR ";
            }

            $sql = substr($sql, 0, -4); // Remove the last 'OR' from the end of the SQL statement
            $sql .= ")";

            if($cityFilter != null){
                $sql .= " AND (";
                 foreach($cityFilter as $city){
                     $sql .= "p.city_id = $city OR ";
                 }
                $sql = substr($sql, 0, -4);
                $sql .= ")";
            }

            // Add sorting statement
            if(strlen($sortBy) >= 1){
                switch($sortBy){
                    case 'dateadded':
                        $sql .= " ORDER BY p.created ASC";
                        break;
                    case 'priceasc':
                        $sql .= " ORDER BY p.totalprice ASC";
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            echo($sql);

            $em = $this->getEntityManager();
            $qb = $em->createQuery($sql);

            $result = $qb->getResult();
        }catch(Exception $ex){
            echo($ex->getMessage());
        }
        return $result;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sorted it out:

```
$sql = "SELECT p FROM Simpleweb\Entity\Product p WHERE ";
```

changed to

```
$sql = "SELECT p FROM Simpleweb\Entity\Product p JOIN p.city c WHERE ";
```

and

```
$sql .= "p.city_id = $city OR ";
```

changed to

```
$sql .= "c.id = $city OR ";
```